# Can a monic polynomial with non-integer rational coefficients have only integer rational roots?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

If $p(x) \in \mathbb Q[x]\smallsetminus \mathbb Z[x]$ be such that all of $p$'s rational roots are integers?

Comment: the polynomial is necessarily monic

Comment: Would you be satisfied with a polynomial with no rational roots?

Comment: $(x^2+\frac{1}{2})(x-2) = x^3 - 2 x^2 + \frac{1}{2} x - 1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A counterexample is that all rational roots of $f(x) = x^2 - \frac{1}{2}$ are integers. This is true vacuously, because it doesn't have any rational roots.

If you insist on having at least one rational root, it's easy to adapt the example: all rational roots of $g(x) = x f(x)$ are integers, and $g(x)$ does indeed have a rational root.

Answer (score 2):

No, at least, not if the polynomial is monic, that is, the polynomial's highest degree coefficient is a one, as suggested in the comments. In this case, if the polynomial had only integer roots $x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n$, we can write the polynomial $P(x)$ as 
$$P(x)=(x-x_1)(x-x_2)...(x-x_n)$$
And thus every term will be an integer, as the only operations we would do to achieve the coefficients are addition and multiplication, both of which are closed operations in the integers.

Comment: It doesn't only have integer roots. It may have other roots, only the RATIONAL ones are integers. So it may have complex roots that are non integers

Comment: Ah. I see, refer to Hurkyl's counterexample I guess.